# With a Spring MVC webapp, can you take a photo on a mobile device and upload it to the server?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, mobile, upload, photo

I was asked to write a webapp using Spring MVC that among other things it must either take a photo on a mobile device or at least upload it from the device's photo library.  Apparently we have some product (probably .NET based) that allows taking/uploading photos from the a web page displayed on a mobile and is where they got the idea from.  Most devices will be iPhones but some might be Android.

1. Is this even possible with a Spring MVC webapp - with no code on the mobile device?
2. If yes, how would you go about designing this?  Is it simply a matter of implementing a file upload as you would from a PC and trust that the mobile device will somehow magically handle the "take a photo" or "pick the photo from the image library", or is there more to it?
3. Is there anything else I need to know about?

Yes, although I am experienced with Spring MVC and even "normal" webapps that are accessed from a mobile... I am clearly clueless about this type of "photo" app.

Comment: “How do I design this” is a question that typically has an hourly rate associated with it.  SO may be able to help if you had a question about your design or implementation, but “how do I do this” is an opinion based answer which are not suitable for this site.

Comment: I’m sorry that you are mistaken about this site’s purpose, but you can modify your question to be more specific and thus get a more meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

write the web app allow access to the camera through the browser of device, when the users take the photo send it to web app or simply create the form allow user select image from device. ( with browser of device you can access camera or folder on device